# Setting up and configuring MySQL Database to store information about billion unique URLs

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am creating an app that stores new information every week consists of 10 X 12 digit integers for about millions of unique URLs. I need to extract information for particular week or for a particular week range for the given URL. I am going to use MySQL as a database.

**Tip:** To simplify, grouping the URLs by domain will reduce the amount of data to processed while querying.

I need advice about structuring a database for fast querying that takes optimal processing power and disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Since no-one else has had a go, here's my advice.

To make a start, ignore 'fast querying that takes optimal processing power and disk space.' Looking for that at the start won't get you anywhere. Design and create a sensible database to meet your function requirements. Bung in random data until you've got approximately the volume you expect. Run queries against it and time them.

If your database is normalised properly, the disc space it takes will also be approximately minimised. Queries may be slow: use execution plans to see why they're slow, and add indexes to help their performance. Once you get acceptable performance, you're there.

The main point is a standard saying: don't optimise until you know you have a problem and you've measured it.

Comment: Thanks for your Comment Simon. I will take your advice. I will first program it then I will measure and optimize it later at the time of testing with test data :)